# AngularJS: validation in model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

How to validate data **inside model** in AngularJS?

I have a form which alters (live) output of some JavaScript code, and in general there are sets of input data that are for some reason invalid (but not single fields being invalid on their own). Unfortunately AngularJS docs point only to defining custom validator directives, which makes no sense for me. It requires a lot of coda and I do not wan't to define logic in HTML (it is not place for it).

Comment: The custom validation directives are not HTML, you would only add the validation attribute to the HTML element you wanted to apply the validation to.

Comment: You could look at this module which removes all validation logic from the markup in regards to showing error messages http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/